# set image in image box from a url with out downloading

Tags: vb.net, image, url

I am writing a program in vb.net for listening to the radio.

How do I make it so I can load a image of the internet with out permanently downloading it to the hard drive. Because if I do this

```
PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/chart/assets/a/aviciivsnickyromero/single/icouldbetheonenicktim/artwork/26948.jpg"
```

but it will say Error   2   Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Drawing.Image'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Download it to an in-memory stream.

```
Dim tClient as WebClient = new WebClient

Dim tImage as Bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(New MemoryStream(tClient.DownloadData(url)))

PictureBox1.Image = tImage
```

Comment: im having 1 Error DownloadStream' is not a member of 'System.Net.WebClient'.

Comment: Dan, thank you for your help. I am a 13 year old boy who is learning to program. You have helped me a lot with my progam. My Dad says thanks as well.

Comment: @IoanLoosley: Keep going :)   Friendly reminder: not everyone online is friendly.  You are bound to run into some comments that seem "unfriendly".  Just remember that you are asking for *free* help from professional programmers.  Don't take it personally and try to learn from everything.

Comment: ill cope with bad comments. I help run a minecraft server when the owners not online. happens all the time.